# RSS Feed for Hot Monthly Questions is named wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed

The feed for hot monthly questions is named Hot Weekly Questions instead of Hot Monthly Questions.

Compare
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/month
to
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good catch, fixed!